# jqGrid custom recordtext and using loadComplete to get records count

Tags: jqgrid, treeview

I am trying to change the `recordtext` of a display grid to a custom format.  I am using a treeview as the selector that refreshes the display grid.   I need to find the total records for the grid and I am able to get this value using the `getGridParam` records method when I click on the treeview node and load the display grid.

However, after I get this value and try to create the custom recordtext, the record count is the previous value, not the current records count.  I know that the `gridComplete` happens before the `loadComplete`, but even placing the get in the `gridComplete` and the set int he `loadComplete`, it still doesn't work, even with a `reloadGrid` trigger.  If I click on the treeview node twice, I get the correct value.

I am thinking it is a timing issue as to when the new value is ready to set the `recordtext`.  Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to try `updatepager` method, which **updates the information on the pager**. Alternatively you can do for example the following:

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
    p.records = 123;
    p.recordtext = "My View {0} - {1} of <i>{2}<i>";
    this.updatepager();
}
```

to see the viewrecords

[image]